# Creating StoragePool

Tags: powershell

This is for PowerShell / Creating a Windows Storage Space.
I have already created a storage pool named TieredStoragePool. It shows three physical disks, mediatype SSD.

An error occurs at the command below:

```
Set-PhysicalDisk –FriendlyName PhysicalDisk1 –MediaType HDD
```

```
Set-PhysicalDisk: The requested object could not be found.
At line:1 char:1
+ Set-PhysicalDisk -FriendlyName PhysicalDisk1 -MediaType HDD
     + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound (PS_StorageCmdlets:ROOT/Microsoft..._StorageCmdlets) [Set-PhysicalDisk], CimException
     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MI RESULT 6, Set-PhysicalDisk
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to check the disks:

```
Get-PhysicalDisk
$disks=Get-PhysicalDisk |? {$_.CanPool -eq $true}
```

Then Create the Storage pool:

```
New-StoragePool -StorageSubSystemFriendlyName *Spaces* -FriendlyName TieredPool -PhysicalDisks $disks
Get-StoragePool -FriendlyName TieredPool | Get-PhysicalDisk | Select FriendlyName, MediaType
```

Then, you should be able to set it:

```
Set-PhysicalDisk -FriendlyName PhysicalDisk1 -MediaType HDD
```

Hope it helps in your understanding.

Comment: I have added New-StorageTier: `New-StorageTier –StoragePoolFriendlyName TieredStoragePool -FriendlyName HDD_Tier –MediaType HDD` after which the FriendlyName changed to PhysicalDisk1, 2, 3, 4 and I was able to change MediaType from SSD into HDD. Can anyone advise some more information? Am a bit confused now, I think. Thanks.

Comment: What kind of information you need. The problem you have faced in the question has been resolved. What are you confused of?  Go through the [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/storage/new-storagepool?view=win10-ps).
Acceptance of the answer would be appreciable.